# Кастомный UI для видеоплеера(MpvPlayerUI.NET) на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ui, mediaplayer

В общем на GitGub нашел библиотеку MpvPlayerUI.NET
https://github.com/mysteryx93/MediaPlayerUI.NET

Плеер сам по себе хорош, что безупречно работает с потоками HLS(m3u8) имеет встроенный UI да и с FullScreen по HotHey проблем нет.
Плеер поставил, все работает.
Выглядит все это дело, как то вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как уверяет разработчик, есть полная поддержка пользовательского интерфейса. На WPF сел совсем недавно и я нифига не могу понять как он меняется.
Могу отключить какие то ненужные мне функции через .cs типа:

```
Player.IsVolumeVisible = false;
Player.IsLoopVisible = false;
Player.IsSpeedVisible = false;
Player.IsStopVisible = false;
```

Но как поменять весь тулбар не пойму. Мне по хорошему нужно поменять только цвет туплбара..да кнопку fullscreen добавить.
Помогите разобраться. А то стандартный тулбар оставляет желать лучшего ")

Comment: Высоко берете. Для начала наверно надо понять как работает сам WPF, верно? Ну а так, вот вроде [стиль](https://github.com/mysteryx93/MediaPlayerUI.NET/blob/master/MediaPlayerUI/Themes/Generic.xaml), делайте на его основе все, что вашей душе будет угодно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ стиль то я видел, даже пытался открыть, но сразу же встречает куча ошибок, то "Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору "PlayerBase.Duration" — доступ только для чтения." то "не содержит определения", то "не существует в пространстве имен". Мне бы понять каким макаром xaml цепляется к "PlayerHost"